# UDF / VBA Problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, udf

I have been trying to use this line of code to bring out a currency however it also bring $[ at the front. Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

````
    Dim s As String
    s = Replace(r.NumberFormat, Chr(34), "")
    txet = ""
    If Len(s) < 3 Then Exit Function
    s = Left(s, 3)
    txet = s
End Function```
````

Comment: Welcome! Please edit question an add header of function. Is it `Function txet(r as Range) As String`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

May be so?

```
Function txet(r As Range) As String
Const NOT_CURRENCY_CHAR As String = "0123456789 .,-"
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer
    s = r.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(NOT_CURRENCY_CHAR)
        s = Replace(s, Mid(NOT_CURRENCY_CHAR, i, 1), "")
    Next i
    txet = s
End Function
```

As far as it became clear from the description of the purpose of your UDF (*to bring out a currency*) you have cells that contain different amounts, formatted as a currency (indicating the currency symbol) - something like "79,46 ₴", "€ 10,09", "35,23 $", "33,57 CHF", "96,70 ₼", "¥ 48,84".

Judging by the code, you tried to isolate the currency symbol from the .NumberFormat property of the cell.
Another approach to solving the problem is proposed: take the text of the cell as it is shown on the screen (this is the [**.Text property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text)), remove all digits, spaces, decimal points and thousands separators from it, the "minus" sign (and, if necessary, the "plus" sign too) - what remains in the string after such cleaning will be the symbol of the currency.

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of what your new code does.

Comment: @spikey_richie Done. The purpose of the loop over the characters of the constant NOT_CURRENCY_CHAR should also be explained?